# Postgresql how to escape comma

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to insert a string like

```
"keyId"=>"5cfd1f5bd6d0c2e6aae4421553a8b3ea","server"=>"http://10.10.27.10/keys/key_file.key","keyRotationPeriod"=>"10"
```

to the database, my current SQL is

```
insert abr.drm(id, name, type, info, ksid, iv)
0, "test", 1, ""keyId"=>"5cfd1f5bd6d0c2e6aae4421553a8b3ea","server"=>"http://10.10.27.10/keys/key_file.key","keyRotationPeriod"=>"10"", NULL, NULL
```

But I got error as

> INSERT has more expressions than target columns,
>   LINE 1: ....10/keys/key_file.key','keyRotationPeriod"=>"10"',NULL,NULL)...
>                                                                ^
>   `
>   how to escape comma in postgresql?

Comment: You are missing the `values` clause. And character values need to be enclosed in **single** quotes, not double quotes. Please see the manual for details: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-populate.html and https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name but this sql `insert abr.drm(id, name, type, info, ksid)
0, "test", 3, ""contentId"=>"15"", 0` works find, the problem appears on the comma.

Comment: No that will **not** work fine because it is invalid SQL

Comment: Are  you doing this via the console or similar program, or is throwing an error as part of a program you're writing?  I'm also concerned because you're putting multiple values into the same column...

Comment: Just use single quotes around your string. Even if double-quotes worked, the problem you need solved isn't how to escape the comma, it would be how to escape your double quotes. Don't worry about escaping either though and use single quotes.